# Bootstrap Tooltip hides selector/toggle element

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 2.3.2.  My tooltips show up as expected, but when hovering off of the triggering element, the tooltip AND the triggering element are both hidden.  There is an inline style of `display:none` being applied to the triggering element.

What is the best way to diagnose why this is happening? I fear it may be another JS library conflicting, but I'm not sure how to capture the event that is adding `display:none` to the triggering element.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the site you're having the issue on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I actually discovered this is a namespacing conflict from interaction between Prototype and Bootstrap 2.3.

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/6921

Best bet is to comment out line `this.$element.trigger(e)` in bootstrap.js for now, or use 3.0 WIP.

Answer (score 4):

Solution *without any change* on bootstrap.js

```
<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">info</span>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();          
    jQuery('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').on("hidden.bs.tooltip", 
         function() { 
          jQuery(this).css("display", "");
    });
});
```

[Reference](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/6921)

Comment: This is a good approach but what do you suggest on the flickering of the element as it hides and again displays from your code??

Comment: Please check my answer below for a non flickering solution

Answer (score 2):

Add this after jquery.js including

```
    jQuery.noConflict();

    //Remove conflict between prototype and bootstrap functions 
    if (Prototype.BrowserFeatures.ElementExtensions) {
        var disablePrototypeJS = function (method, pluginsToDisable) {
            var handler = function (event) {
                event.target[method] = undefined;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    delete event.target[method];
                }, 0);
            };
            pluginsToDisable.each(function (plugin) { 
                jQuery(window).on(method + '.bs.' + plugin, handler);
            });
        },
        pluginsToDisable = ['collapse', 'dropdown', 'modal', 'tooltip', 'popover', 'tab'];
        disablePrototypeJS('show', pluginsToDisable);
        disablePrototypeJS('hide', pluginsToDisable);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution does not flicker...

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
.on('hide.bs.tooltip', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div.tooltip').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For the googlers; for me all of the answers did not work. So here is (not the best) but a really simple workaround:

Add this to your css:

```
[data-toggle="tooltip"] {
  display: initial !important;
}
```